# pyroscope: how to use py-spy configs in pyroscope python client

Tags: python, profiling

I have recently used [Pyroscope](https://github.com/pyroscope-io/pyroscope) for my python program. It uses py-spy for profiling the programs. I have checked the configuration of [the Pyroscope python client](https://github.com/pyroscope-io/pyroscope-python), and the configs are very limited which described in [the configure method](https://github.com/pyroscope-io/pyroscope-python/blob/11e524cf8fc9f50278ce57a104b50083e7874973/pyroscope/__init__.py#L14). I want to use some of the py-spy configs like `--native` or `--idle` as described on the [py-spy GitHub page](https://github.com/benfred/py-spy#how-do-you-detect-if-a-thread-is-idle-or-not). How can I use it in the python client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question in [this issue](https://github.com/pyroscope-io/pyroscope/issues/1163) and in the new version, they added the options in `pyroscope.configs()` like they describe in full documentations on [this link](https://pyroscope.io/docs/python/#full-configuration)